# GRPC Multiprocessing not working in Python

Tags: grpc, grpc-python

I'm trying grpc multiprocess example listed here on OSX -
https://github.com/grpc/grpc/tree/74bba2c90a4f4607674a01ec1c0b634708fea887/examples/python/multiprocessing

```
[PID 19271] Binding to 'localhost:50976'
[PID 19292] Starting new server.
[PID 19293] Starting new server.
[PID 19294] Starting new server.
[PID 19295] Starting new server.
[PID 19296] Starting new server.
[PID 19297] Starting new server.
[PID 19298] Starting new server.
[PID 19299] Starting new server.
[PID 19300] Starting new server.
[PID 19301] Starting new server.
[PID 19302] Starting new server.
[PID 19303] Starting new server.
[PID 19304] Starting new server.
[PID 19305] Starting new server.
[PID 19306] Starting new server.
[PID 19307] Starting new server.
```

I do see multiple server processes started. However, on running the client, I see only one of the server PID logged in server logs. Sample logs below. I expected it to be spread across all the server processes. Am I missing something here?

```
[PID 19295] Determining primality of 1139
[PID 19295] Determining primality of 779
[PID 19295] Determining primality of 1709
[PID 19295] Determining primality of 563
[PID 19295] Determining primality of 1493
[PID 19295] Determining primality of 226
[PID 19295] Determining primality of 1140
[PID 19295] Determining primality of 2027
[PID 19295] Determining primality of 2334
[PID 19295] Determining primality of 564
[PID 19295] Determining primality of 1494
```

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a problem with OSX. I tried this in Ubuntu and it works fine with all the server PIDs being used.